# Is there a `?.` operator in Python?

Tags: python, null, operator-keyword, ternary

Groovy has a very handy operator `?.`. This checks if the object is not `null` and, if it is not, accesses a method or a property. Can I do the same thing in Python?

The closest I have found is the [ternary conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python). Right now I am doing

```
l = u.find('loc')
l = l.string if l else None
```

whereas it would be nice to write

```
l = u.find('loc')?.string
```

**Update**: in addition to `getattr` mentioned below, I found a relatively nice way to do it with a list:

`[x.string if x else None for x in [u.find('loc'), u.find('priority'), ...]]`

Another alternative, if you want to exclude `None`:

`[x.string for x in [u.find('loc'), u.find('priority'), ...] if x]`

Comment: Don't think there is anything better than your current method in Python.  You could use `l = l and l.string` for the second line but this is significantly less readable and doesn't save much typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write something like this

```
L = L and L.string
```

Important to note that as in your ternary example, this will do the "else" part for any "Falsy" value of L

If you need to check specifically for None, it's clearer to write

```
if L is not None:
    L = L.string
```

or for the any "Falsy" version

```
if L:
    L = L.string
```

I think using `getattr` is kind of awkward for this too

```
L = getattr(L, 'string', None)
```

Comment: Actually, `getattr` is kind of nice. We get `getattr(u.find('loc'), 'string', None)`, which is still a one-liner.